# Are there important differences between a 401k and 403b plan?

Tags: united-states, 401k, 403b

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are 401(k), 403(b), and 457(b) tax-advantaged retirement plans different?  How are they alike?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/725/how-are-401k-403b-and-457b-tax-advantaged-retirement-plans-different-ho)

I work for a non profit and as such my retirement plan is a 403(b) rather than a 401(k) plan. I know these refer to different parts of the same law, but I don't know if there are any substantive differences in the plans. 
Does anyone know if there are big differences or is it really just a different name for the same thing?